# Copy-item command worked in target VM but not start-process command when working image template creation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am using image template to create the image and during creation of image template in the customizations section.

[image]

I have added PowerShell command for each set of commands below.

**PowerShell command 1:**

```
New-Item -Type Directory -Path 'c:\' -Name Java, 
invoke-webrequest -uri 'https://download.oracle.com/java/21/latest/jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi' -OutFile 'c:\temp\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi', 
copy-item 'c:\temp\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi\' -Destination 'c:\temp'
```

**PowerShell Command 2:**

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi\'
```

**PowerShell command 3:**

```
# Set the name and value of the environment variable
$variableName = "JAVA_HOME" $variableValue = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin"

# Use [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable method to set the environment variable
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableName, $variableValue, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

# Display a message indicating that the variable has been added
Write-Host "Environment variable $variableName set to $variableValue"
```

**PowerShell command 4:**

```
New-Item -Type Directory -Path 'c:\' -Name Python, invoke-webrequest -uri 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.1/python-3.12.1-amd64.exe' -OutFile 'c:\temp\python-3.12.1-amd64.exe', copy-item 'c:\temp\python-3.12.1-amd64.exe\' -Destination 'c:\temp' PowerShell command5: Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\python-3.12.1-amd64.exei\'
```

I only see folders and .exe and MSI files copied in to the target VM but not executed .msi and .exe file that means only PowerShell command 1 and 4 worked but other commands not worked,

Please suggest a fix for this.  I have not seen any error after image template got created.

what could be the wrong with other commands?

You can see start process working inside VM which after I have tested

[image]

Copy-items is working but .exe is not working, I tried all the ways to make sure .exe gets executed

Comment: Please check if the **MSI** file is available in the specified directory. If the file does not exist, do not install it and do not add the path to the environment variables. There is no issue with the command, as it's **working** for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copy-item command worked in target VM but not start-process command when working image template creation.

If the `MSI` file is not installing using the `Start-Process` command, you may need to check the following steps.

- Check the paths of the `MSI file` to ensure they are correct.
- Make sure to check the MSI file is available in specified path.

Here is the updated script to install `MSI` application with condition to test the **MSI** file located in the path.

```
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path 'c:\' -Name Java
    
    invoke-webrequest -uri 'https://download.oracle.com/java/21/latest/jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi' -OutFile 'C:\Users\v-vallepuv\Downloads\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi'
    
    copy-item 'C:\Users\v-vallepuv\Downloads\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi' -Destination 'c:\Java' 
    
    $file = "c:\Java\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi"
    
    if (Test-Path $file) {
        # If the file exists, display the file name
        Write-Host "File found: $file"
    
        $hostname = hostname
    
        Write-Host "JDK-21 installation has started on the device : $hostname"
    
        Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\Java\jdk-21_windows-x64_bin.msi' /qn -Wait
    
        Write-Host "jdk-21 has been installed sucessfully on the device : $hostname "
    
        # Set the name and value of the environment variable
        $variableName = "JAVA_HOME" 
    
         $variableValue = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin"
    
         # Use [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable method to set the environment variable
          [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableName, $variableValue, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
    
           # Display a message indicating that the variable has been added
          Write-Host "Environment variable $variableName set to $variableValue on the device :$hostname " 
    
    } 
       else {
        # If the file does not exist, display a message indicating it
        Write-Host "File not found: $file"
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

The `JDK` application has been installed successfully on local device with `environment` variables.

[image]